# Update an entity with new values

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a Book entity which is a composite consisting of a list of Chapter entities. I am creating a RESTful web service and one of the endpoints is `/books/1/chapters/3` which responds to the PUT method to update a chapter.

What would be a good way of updating a existing chapter in the list that the book have? Copying each value in the controller layer doesn't seem very smart, and creating a partial Chapter entity to pass to an `update` method on the Chapter entity that copies each field would mean that I have inconsisted chapters in the system.